# Return null instead default value in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have LINQ query which has to retreive some DateTime value. Somethimes I don't have match for and I have to return NULL for that DateTime value instead default value for DateTime.

How can I avoid that and return NULL instead defaul value?

My LINQ:

```
CreatedDate = ctaMatch.Select(d => d.CreatedDate).DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault()
```

In DefaultIfEmpty I can put only DateTime.

Comment: You can't have a null DateTime, because it is a value type. You can use a nullable type (`DateTime?`).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Cast it to `DateTime?` that will cause `DefaultIfEmpty` creates a default collection that contains null value if the collection is empty.

```
CreatedDate = ctaMatch
    .Select(d => (DateTime?)d.CreatedDate)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

**PS:** The `DefaultIfEmpty` can be omitted, because it's followed by `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: By using `DefaultIfEmpty()`, doesn't this make the `Default` in `FirstOrDefault()` redundant? Should this be `First()`?

Comment: @Sam, yes if it's followed by `FirstOrDefault` it's not required.

Comment: Very cool trick with casting to nullable DateTime. This changes behaviour of FirstOrDefault to return null instead of default values when it comes to scalars

Answer (score 14):

You could use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators), `?.` on the object hosting your date property:

```
DateTime? date = ctaMatch.FirstOrDefault()?.CreatedDate;
```

If `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` for your collection, the null-conditional operator will return `null` for the `CreatedDate` property.

Alternatively, you could select your dates and cast them explicitly to [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
DateTime? date = ctaMatch.Select(d => (DateTime?)d.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

... thereby giving it a default value of `null`.

Comment: I guess you can write a general extension method, `public static TValue? FirstOrNull<TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> source) where TValue : struct { return source.Select(x => (TValue?)x).FirstOrDefault(); }`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative syntax... get the `First` element if `Any` exist; otherwise use `null`:

```
DateTime? CreatedDate = ctaMatch.Any() ? ctaMatch.First().CreatedDate : (DateTime?)null;
```

Comment: Is the last cast neccessary? `(DateTime?)`. If `CreatedDate` is of type DateTime? then assigning just `null` does the job. `CreatedDate = ctaMatch.Any() ? ctaMatch.First() : null;`

Comment: @broadband If `CreatedDate` were of type `DateTime?` already, then you're right - the cast would be unnecessary. In the OP's case though, `CreatedDate` was a non-nullable `DateTime`, and so the default value was "1/1/0001", which he didn't want. In that case, the cast is necessary.

Comment: I suppose you mean by non-nullable `DateTime` just `DateTime createdDate` (without `?` at the end of `DateTime`). Even if CreatedDate is non-nullable you can't assign with DateTime cast. `DateTime CreatedDate = (DateTime?)null; won't compile`