# How to reutrn null for a specific field

Tags: c#, linq

My question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539139/return-null-instead-default-value-in-linq) SO post. This helped me to return null, but how can I return null for a specific field

Example

```
select new FlowerMetaData
{
    FlowerId = flowers.FlowerId,
    UpdatedDate = flowers.UpdatedDate,
    FlowerDates = FlowerDates.OrderBy(d => d.CreatedDate).ToList(),
    ClosedDate = FlowerDates
        .Where(c => c.FlowerType == "Rainbow Rose" || c.FlowerType == "Black Rose" || c.FlowerType == "SunFlower" || c.FlowerType == "Lotus" || c.FlowerType == "Tulip" || c.FlowerType == "Rose")
        .Any()
           ? flowersDates.Where(c => c.FlowerType == "Rainbow Rose" || c.FlowerType == "Black Rose" || c.FlowerType == "SunFlower" || c.FlowerType == "Lotus" || c.FlowerType == "Tulip" || c.FlowerType == "Rose").OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Select(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault()
           : (DateTime?)null
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to return null for closed date only.

Comment: Even reading the linked post, I have no idea what you want. Can you be more specific in what your result is supposed to be?

Comment: Show your `FlowerMetaData` class

Comment: @nvoigt, the result is that If closed date is null. It should return null for that specific field and not make the entire Selection null

Comment: It looks like we are missing a `from ... ` + possible `where` at the beginning. It would help to include those, because without it the `FirstOrDefault()` at the end makes no sense.

Comment: @PeterB, this is not the entire query. I have from ... above the select.

Comment: I meant you need to show it *here*, or at least add something to make it syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only `FirsOrDefault`:

```
...
ClosedDate = FlowerDates.Where(c =>new string[] {"Rainbow Rose", 
                                             "Black Rose",
                                             "SunFlower",
                                             "Lotus",
                                             "Tulip",
                                             "Rose"}.Contains( c.FlowerType))
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
                        .Select(x =>(DateTime?) x.CreatedDate)
                        .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Also is when you have so many or conditions is good idea use `Contains` extension method. If there is not element that meets the condition then the result will be `null`.

Comment: I dont see .Contains when i do that :-S

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I am using that

Comment: Sorry I was not using intellisense, I forgot `new`

Comment: I was getting the same result with this query but when I changed the select to `Select(x => (DateTime?)x.CreatedDate)
                        .FirstOrDefault()`. It worked.

Comment: Right, DateTime default value is not  `null`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is essentially already working, but there's a lot of convoluted code confusing the issue.

I take it that your problem boils down to conditionally setting `ClosedDate` based on whether or not `Any()` evaluates to true:

```
void Main()
{
    var FlowerDates = new List<Flower>();
    FlowerDates.Add(new Flower {FlowerId =1});//Comment this out and you will get NULL
    FlowerDates.Add(new Flower {FlowerId =2});

    //I simplified the condition to focus on choosing a null value
    //If Any() evaluates to true then get current time, else return null
    //Yes you are doing a projection here, but setting a variable is effectively the same thing and simpler to follow
    var ClosedDate = FlowerDates.Where(c => c.FlowerId == 1)
        .Any()
           ? DateTime.Now
           : (DateTime?)null;

    //ClosedDate is either NULL or DateTime.Now depending on Any()
}

public class Flower
{
    public int FlowerId { get; set; }
}
```